# Background image class is being chopped in chrome and firefox, not safari

Tags: html, css, browser

I use live server extension in VS code. I add an image to the background in the css using the .about class. Im testing in chrome through the live server and everything is working. I compress my files and upload it to my hosting site. When i access the live site i do not see the background image. When i inspect i see that my css class about is not there, if i add it manually via developer tools in the browser, the background image appears. When I check my code that has been uploaded, sure enough the .about class is there as it should be. What could be causing this? It works fine in all browsers through live server, then decides to cut out that class on the live server.

I have tried changing the class to id. changed the path to the image as well. Re-uploaded code to hosting site, tried incognito mode.

'''

```
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-12 d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="about-text">
        <small class="small-text">Welcome to <span class="mobile-block">my website!</span></small>
        <h1 class="animated animated-text">
          <span class="mr-2">Hello, I am a</span>
          <div class="animated-info">
            <span class="animated-item">Guitarist</span>
            <span class="animated-item">Musician</span>
            <span class="animated-item">Legend.</span>
          </div>
        </h1>

        <p>Joe, maybe say a few words about yourself here.</p>

        <div class="custom-btn-group mt-4">
          <a href="#" class="btn mr-lg-2 custom-btn"><i class='fab fa-paypal'></i> Donate</a>
          <a href="#contact" class="btn custom-btn custom-btn-bg custom-btn-link">Contact me</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-12">
      <div class="about-image svg">
        <img src="./img/Old-Fashioned-Guitar-Silhouette-Design-white.png" class="img-fluid" alt="svg image">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

'''

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Not sure what was causing the browser to omit that css class, but it's now working. I will re-post if it acts up again.

Comment: @maathimselft if this post already works and doesn't have a question I would delete it.